# Get data using Soql ,where week starts on Monday (not Sunday)

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to count the number of new opportunities by week where the week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday. I can get the query to work fine when the week starts on Sunday (which is the default), but can't figure out how to get the week to calculate to start on a Monday and end on Sunday. Appreciate any suggestions on the issue.

```
SELECT   WEEK_IN_MONTH(CloseDate) week,COUNT(Id) total FROM Opportunity where Calendar_Month(CloseDate)=9 and StageName!='Closed-Lost' GROUP BY WEEK_IN_MONTH(CloseDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change your date locale preferences in Personal Setup to a locale that starts their week on Monday. All date and time functions in SOQL use these settings to determine when days and weeks start and end.

Comment: thanks, @sfdcfox.Around 500 users are using this lwc component. It will be difficult to change the locale of all 500 users. Even if we change for them it causes confusion for them in other standard pages for the end-users. Looking to do it without local change.

Comment: @KumaraRavuri You'd have to group by calendar_day/calendar_month and then do the calculation in your component, then.

Comment: @KumaraRavuri And, by the way, this is why it's important to be as detailed as possible when you ask questions, because those details totally change the answer.